# How to send "thank you" emails to donors?

Tags: email, contributions

We want to send emails to our donors of the previous week. This email needs to be customised, as it's an opportunity to tell them what has happen in the week or what's the plan to the week ahead.

I tried to use the thank you letter feature, but I haven't been able to customise much of the email (eg. the subject line) easily for each mailing.

If I do a "normal" mailing from an advanced search on donors, I haven't found an easy way to set the "thank you" date on the contribution, and only filtering on the contribution date isn't robust enough, and I'd like to use that field to know as well when the donor has received the thank you email.

Comment: Eileen's civitoken extension (i think, which may need entitysetting extension too) gives you access to tokens like 'last contribution' etc and may therefore also provide 'date of last donation' but haven't double checked so not offering as an answer, but can flesh out if that seems useful. civirules idea seems better though.

Comment: like it pete, but doesn't solve the problem of setting up the thank you date on the contrib

Comment: true - i didn't really take that bit in

Answer (score 4):

Although it will not be a completely clear-cut solution without any work, you could try to use CiviRules? It allows you to specify sending a email to the donor 1 week after the actual receipt of the contribution. You can specify the template, which will probably require some work to do exactly what you want it to do, but it might be worth a try?

Comment: nice idea. is civirule working on 4.6?

Comment: Yes, we have tested it against 4.6 in December

Comment: @Xavier You could simultanously use CiviRules to set thank you date as well. CiviRules have the possibility to set multiple actions for each trigger. So, you could send an email AND set the thank you date. That would in fact do exactly the same as the native "send thank you"-functionality, PLUS that you could set it to act automatically:-)

Answer (score 2):

I think if you search contributions instead of contacts, you can do exactly what you want out of the box.

Comment: To add to this: There are 2 similar looking but completely different email templates: contacts vs. contributions.  The latter has tokens on the contribution and should provide what you want.  Using a bit of smarty can also help if you have the skills.

Answer (score 0):

The code that places the default subject line "Thank you for your contribution/s" is in this file. /CRM/Contribute/Form/Task/PDFLetterCommon.php

It's hardcoded in there but I can't imagine other's wouldn't appreciate a quick fix that sends the "Activity Subject" as the email subject line.